# ARKit Place a SCNNode facing the camera

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode, arscnview

I'm using `ARKit` to display 3D objects. I managed to place the nodes in the real world in front of the user (aka the camera). But I don't manage to make them to face the camera when I drop them.

```
let tap_point=CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
let results=arscn_view.hitTest(tap_point, types: .estimatedHorizontalPlane)
guard results.count>0 else{
    return
}
guard let r=results.first else{
    return
}

let hit_tf=SCNMatrix4(r.worldTransform)
let new_pos=SCNVector3Make(hit_tf.m41, hit_tf.m42+Float(0.2), hit_tf.m43)

guard let scene=SCNScene(named: file_name) else{
    return
}
guard let node=scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Mesh", recursively: true) else{
    return
}
node.position=new_pos
arscn_view.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

The nodes are well positioned on the plane, in front of the camera. But they are all looking in the same direction. I guess I should **rotate** the `SCNNode` but I didn't manage to do this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49151332/3151675

Answer (score 8):

First, get the rotation matrix of the camera:

```
let rotate = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.eulerAngles.y, 0, 1, 0))
```

Then, combine the matrices:

```
let rotateTransform = simd_mul(r.worldTransform, rotate)
```

Lastly, apply a transform to your node, casting as SCNMatrix4:

```
node.transform = SCNMatrix4(rotateTransform)
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

here how you can create SCNMatrix4  from simd_float4x4

```
   let rotateTransform = simd_mul(r.worldTransform, rotate)

  node.transform =  SCNMatrix4(m11: rotateTransform.columns.0.x, m12: rotateTransform.columns.0.y, m13: rotateTransform.columns.0.z, m14: rotateTransform.columns.0.w, m21: rotateTransform.columns.1.x, m22: rotateTransform.columns.1.y, m23: rotateTransform.columns.1.z, m24: rotateTransform.columns.1.w, m31: rotateTransform.columns.2.x, m32: rotateTransform.columns.2.y, m33: rotateTransform.columns.2.z, m34: rotateTransform.columns.2.w, m41: rotateTransform.columns.3.x, m42: rotateTransform.columns.3.y, m43: rotateTransform.columns.3.z, m44: rotateTransform.columns.3.w)
```

Comment: What is "r.worldTransform" referring to? I don't see what it could be.

Comment: "r" is just the TC's variable for results.first, meaning the user's first touch point on the screen (I'm assuming within their touchesBegan method). The documentation explains it best, worldTransform is "The transformation matrix that defines the intersection’s rotation, translation and scale relative to the world."

Comment: Ahh okay, i get what world transform is/does, just not where r came from, thanks!

Comment: thank you!!! I swear yours is the only answer on stack overflow that worked for me! adding a node as child of camera would make the node follow it, with your way instead it is only initially oriented towards the camera but stays in place. in my case I would extract a `SCNVector3` inside `touchesBegan` to use as position of my `textNode` and then apply the `rotateTransform` as you showed. Thanks Again, this should be marked as the answer @op

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you out.

Comment: what does TC stand for?

Comment: It just means Topic Creator

Comment: I am trying to do this in a method that gets called every second and after about 20 seconds it crashes. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @Psonthalia Your situation is quite vague, may I ask why you require calling this method every second? If you want a node to continually face the user, I would look into SCNBillboardConstraint.

Comment: I was calling it every second since I wanted the node to constantly face the camera. I think I was able to find an odd solution. I was calling a function that caused the issue. After I copied the code from the function and put it into the class itself, it started working. Not sure what is going on, but it works

Comment: You definitely want SCNBillboardConstraint then as it does exactly what you are looking for without needing to do something every second.

Answer (score 5):

```
guard let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
    return
}
node.eulerAngles.y = frame.camera.eulerAngles.y
```

Comment: I was looking for this for the past couple of days. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

here's my code for the SCNNode facing the camera..hope help for someone

```
    let location = touches.first!.location(in: sceneView)

    var hitTestOptions = [SCNHitTestOption: Any]()
    hitTestOptions[SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly] = true

    let hitResultsFeaturePoints: [ARHitTestResult]  = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .featurePoint)

    let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(location)
    guard let node = hitTestResults.first?.node else {
        if let hit = hitResultsFeaturePoints.first {
            let rotate = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.eulerAngles.y, 0, 1, 0))
            let finalTransform = simd_mul(hit.worldTransform, rotate)
            sceneView.session.add(anchor: ARAnchor(transform: finalTransform))
        }
        return
    }
```

Comment: Not work for me :\ , The anchor isn't facing the camera in all angles..

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the nodes to always face the camera, even as the camera moves? That's what SceneKit [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/constraints) are for. Either `SCNLookAtConstraint` or `SCNBillboardConstraint` can keep a node always pointing at the camera.

Do you want the node to face the camera when placed, but then hold still (so you can move the camera around and see the back of it)? There are a few ways to do that. Some involve fun math, but a simpler way to handle it might just be to design your 3D assets so that "front" is always in the positive Z-axis direction. Set a placed object's transform based on the camera transform, and its initial orientation will match the camera's.

Comment: The second :) I want the node to face the camera when I place it then keep it here (and be able to move around).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say > design your 3D assets so that "front" is always in the positive Z-axis direction. I have a dae file I converted to scn in xCode. The node position is (0, 0, 0). But I also placed the camera at (0, 0, 0.9) in order to have the object in front of me. Might be important to precise the camera is in the node hierarchy (a subnode I guess).

Comment: Nodes are always right positioned in front of the camera when I drop them, they are visible (no behind the camera). If I move in the room and drop several nodes they are all kind of parallels. When I drop the first node, it is "looking at me". But not the next ones. I don't know if what I say is clear... :/

Comment: If you are bringing your DAE in from Blender you have to rotate it -90 degrees.

Comment: @MarieDm did you resolve this issue? I am also facing the same issue and couldn't find a concrete solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Venkatesh, no I didn't... :( I have not been working on this since a few weeks ago and have not find any solution unfortunately.

Comment: @PruitIgoe why do you have to rotate if the DAE comes from Blender?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this but if I remember correctly the DAE from Blender comes oriented differently, so in order for it to appear correctly in the app you need to adjust it by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
func faceCamera() {
    guard constraints?.isEmpty ?? true else {
        return
    }
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 5
    SCNTransaction.completionBlock = { [weak self] in
        self?.constraints = []
    }
    constraints = [billboardConstraint]
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}

private lazy var billboardConstraint: SCNBillboardConstraint = {
    let constraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
    constraint.freeAxes = [.Y]
    return constraint
}()
```

As stated earlier a `SCNBillboardConstraint` will make the node always look at the camera. I am animating it so the node doesn't just immediately snap into place, this is optional. In the `SCNTransaction.completionBlock` I remove the constraint, also optional.

Also I set the `SCNBillboardConstraint`'s `freeAxes`, which customizes on what axis the node follows the camera, again optional.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the node to face the camera when I place it then keep it here (and be able to move around). – Marie Dm
>   Blockquote

You can put object facing to camera, using this:

```
if let rotate = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform {
    node.simdTransform = rotate
}
```

This code will save you from [gimbal lock](http://www.anticz.com/eularqua.htm) and other troubles.

> The four-component rotation vector specifies the direction of the rotation axis in the first three components and the angle of rotation (in radians) in the fourth. The default rotation is the zero vector, specifying no rotation. Rotation is applied relative to the node’s simdPivot property.
>
> The simdRotation, simdEulerAngles, and simdOrientation properties all affect the rotational aspect of the node’s simdTransform property. Any change to one of these properties is reflected in the others.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881845-simdrotation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881843-simdtransform

Comment: This fixed the gimbal lock for me, but I only needed the camera's orientation, not its size: `node.simdOrientation = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform.orientation`